# I've scraped a video from a website and downloaded it, the video is not playing

Tags: python, web-scraping, youtube, python-requests, video-streaming

I need to download video from "https://www.thewatchcartoononline.tv/bobs-burgers-season-9-episode-5-live-and-let-fly" and play it. I'm able to download it as "bobs.burgers.s09e03.mp4" but not able to play it!

```py
import requests
import bs4
url = 'https://www.thewatchcartoononline.tv/bobs-burgers-season-9-episode-5-live-and-let-fly'
def download_file(url, filename):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
    return (filename)

download_file(url, "bobs.burgers.s09e03.mp4")
```

I think the video should download and played.

Comment: Use a hex editor/viewer to look at the file to find out what you really got.

Comment: or for basic test, edit your Q to show the output from  `file bobs.burgers.s09e03.mp4` ? Good luck.

Comment: Consider buying your media legally... it might work better.

Comment: You download the html. Try view source and look for the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect a video after writing a script to download the web page. Your code downloads the web page and stores it in a .mp4 file. The following code deos the job correctly.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.thewatchcartoononline.tv/inc/embed/getvidlink.php?v=cizgi/bobs.burgers.s09e05.mp4&embed=cizgi&hd=1'

def get_url(url):

    page = requests.get(url,headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest','User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'}).json()
    download_url = page['cdn']+'/getvid?evid='+page['enc']

    return download_url

def download_video(url,filename):
    r= requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'},stream=True)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
    return (filename)

download_video(get_url(url),"bobs.burgers.s09e03.mp4")
```